# AD7705 vs TM7705?

Tags: adc

After some research I found the AD7705. To test it I bough two ICs. The ICs cost at least 4USD.
The I saw an article about a little PCB with that chip which cost 2USD.
https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-16-bit-500SPS-Dual-Channel-DAQ/

When I look at the pictures it's not the AD7705 but a TM7705 on these modules.
In the description they are described as compatible with no further info.

**Does anybody of you know the differences of the AD7705 and the TM7705?**

Here is a sample for a cheap board:
http://www.micontechlab.com/product/936/1x-tm7705-dual-16-bit-a-d-module-compatible-ad7705-spi-interface
I include that link because it includes multiple pictures. There are others with the same board and lower prices.

Comment: Do you know what a manufacturer's data sheet is? If not then this is what you need to learn about first. Then get such data sheets from the two manufacturers of the parts and have a comparative look.

Comment: by the way: instructables are often not a very good source of electronics information. this one is no exception. It's premise is "I needed to sample an analog signal with as many bits and samples per second as possible but without breaking the bank." Anyone with signal processing basics will tell you that statement makes no sense: your analog signal has a bandwidth, and sampling higher than necessary makes no sense, and sampling lower than necessary makes no sense either. Your system has noise, and sampling with more bits than your SNR meaningfully allows makes no sense.

Comment: So, really, that instructable's author might actually be happy with their ADC – but they haven't demonstrated any ability to define what their requirements for happiness were to begin with. Don't make the same mistake! You need to write down requirements first, and check whether a given device / system fulfills them. Then, you can use that. Without requirement, you could use a wet piece of wood as ADC, just as well: it has a humongous quantization error, but since you never specified what you needed, that would still be within specs.

Comment: Google TM7705 datasheet. Download same. Compare the specs you're interested in with the AD7705.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Obviously I googled first for such datasheet. Maybe it's hidden somewhere but until now I did not find it. It seems to me like a want-to-be AD7705 and that's about it.

Comment: They're made in Shenzhen by Titan Microelectronics. Datasheet [here](http://www.titanmec.com/index.php/en/product/download/id/597.html) . They're probably okay.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I saw the datasheet yesterday and commented about it below. The TM datasheet contains "measured" data from the original AD datasheet. That shows that nobody should trust that datasheet because it contains measurements from a different device from a different manufacturer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anybody of you know the differences of the AD7705 and the TM7705?

Yes, whoever produces the TM7705 knows the differences.

It's what it's called a *clone*: a device meant to fulfill the same role, with the same specs. However, the fact that it's much cheaper probably means the manufacturer of the TM chip needed to go for a few compromises: Higher power consumption, lower accurracy, higher probability of error, more noise, higher thermal dependency, less supply noise rejection, lower safety margins for ESD and overvoltages, that kind of thing.

That needn't be a bad thing: There's plenty of clones that are as good as the original for many use cases. If you go back in computer history, you'll find that a lot of progress was made due to people first cloning a successful device, then improving it (i386, the 8051, opamps…).

However, the point is that a clone *is not the same device*. It's simply not. So, a useful clone would come with a datasheet that you can read on your own to verify it does what you need it to do. Just like the AD7705!

Now, you can't find a datasheet for that clone. So, that's a bad device: All you *really* know about it is its name, and that *maybe* the manufacurer of it wants it to be used in places where the AD7705 might be used. Under which conditions? We don't know. With what guarantees? None.

So, it's the same for clones as for any other electronic component: No datasheet, no sale. Buying something that you don't know what it'll do in the future is a terrible idea, no matter how cheap it is.

I assume you went through quite a few ADC datasheets before you selected the AD7705 (seeing it's a speciality device); you *know* that you have special requirements. If there's no document *from the manufacturer* that states their device fulfills your requirements, you can't buy it.

Comment: Yes, I looked at a lot of datasheets before I found the AD7705. I guess it's obvious that I do this only as a hobby. For initial testing and programming of an ESP32 I bought the original AD7705 chip. But to test this I obviously have to build a small circuit. Then when I saw that clone I thought I can use that at the beginning so I don't have to build my own PCB just to start. And I thought maybe someone here tested that already, this is why I asked. But then again I should have known that I should be careful with questions like this here with the experts...

Comment: @Edgar I quite like your question! And I think what I wrote is true both for people that do this for a living, and as a hobby: While you might save at most 4 €, the headache if it doesn't work and you don't know whether you've made a mistake or the IC just behaves differently than the AD7705 is probably not worth it – especially if you don't have the measurement equipment to look at your digital signals exactly and verify you're actually doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

I did exactly the same as you.
While looking for an AD7705 evaluation board, I came across the red TM7705 based board on AliExpress.

Here is the ["Titan Micro" data sheet](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Analog-To-Digital-Converters-ADCs_TM7705_C84305.html).
And [that of AD7705](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7705_7706.pdf).
Don't read Chinese, so I haven't tried to compare the two chips in detail.
I have only found that TM7705 is pin to pin compatible with the Analog Device chip.
Convinced that it also has similar characteristics.

Comment: I just had a look at that data sheet and compared it a little with the AD7705. It seems the data sheet is mostly also a copy. I.e. on the page Typical Performance Characteristics is a graph which is 1:1 copied from the original to the TM. So it seems they didn't do their own testing but just copied a graph from the original. Bad! One interesting difference is that the TM7705 seems to have also an internal reverence voltage of 2.5V. That is shown in the block diagram of the TM but not on the AD. Until now I didn't test any of them but I definitely don't trust the fake with fake datasheet.